# Finding the distance to the nearest 0 in a list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I have a code that finds the distance of each element of the list to the nearest 0:

```
lst = [2, 1, 0, 3, 5]
length = len(lst)
dist = []

for i in lst:
    if lst.index(0) > lst.index(i):
        diff = lst.index(0) - lst.index(i)
        dist.append(diff)
    elif lst.index(0) < lst.index(i):
        diff = abs(lst.index(i)) - abs(lst.index(0))
        dist.append(diff)
    elif lst.index(0) == lst.index(i):
        dist.append(0)
print(dist)

# Output: [2, 1, 0, 1, 2]
```

Currently it works only when there is one 0 in a list.

How to modify code so that it works with **any** number of 0s in the list?

If second 0 is added to the list, than the output gets broken.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. First off: do you understand *why* you get the result that you do? Second: How would you solve the problem by hand? What algorithm do you want to implement - what do you imagine are the logical steps that need to be followed in order to solve the problem?

Comment: Hint: try **reading the documentation** for the `index` method. See how it has `start` and `stop` parameters, and how they can be used to search starting from a specific point? You should also see a `rindex` method for lists, which searches backwards (the `r` stands for "reverse"). Can you think of a good starting point to search for a zero, both forwards and backwards, that would make it easy to solve the problem?

Comment: Aside from that: is the question really about getting the result for a single index, or for all of them? Because if you want to calculate all the values at once, it can be done faster than looping to calculate each one individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`index(0)` will only get you the first occurrence of `0` -- for that matter, `index(i)` will only get you the first occurrence of the value `i`, so if you had (say) multiple `5`s in your list, your output would calculate the distance between the first `5` and the first `0`, and report that for both `5`s.

What I might suggest is getting the indices of all the zeroes in a list comprehension:

```
zeroes = [i for i, val in enumerate(lst) if val == 0]
```

and then you can get the distance to the closest zero for each index by taking the `min` distance across that `zeroes` list (this isn't the absolute most efficient way, since it's O(n^2) for a list that's nothing but zeroes, but it has the advantage of being extremely simple):

```
dist = [min(abs(i - z) for z in zeroes) for i in range(len(lst))]
```

If we pop those two lines of code into a function it's easy to try it out with different lists:

```
>>> def zero_dist(lst):
...     zeroes = [i for i, val in enumerate(lst) if val == 0]
...     return [min(abs(i - z) for z in zeroes) for i in range(len(lst))]
...
>>> zero_dist([2, 1, 0, 3, 5])
[2, 1, 0, 1, 2]
>>> zero_dist([5, 1, 0, 3, 0, 5])
[2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

If you want something that's O(n) even when there are lots of zeroes, you need to make sure that you're not iterating over the entire original list of numbers *or* the list of all zeroes within your main loop body.  Here's one possible approach that's based on building the list of zero indices and popping items off it as you go through the main loop, so that you're only ever looking at the two nearest zero indices:

```
def zero_dist(nums: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    zeroes = [i for i, val in enumerate(nums) if val == 0][::-1]
    dist: list[int] = []
    z = next_z = zeroes.pop()  # raises IndexError if no zeroes
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if i == next_z:
            z, next_z = next_z, zeroes.pop() if zeroes else -1
        dist.append(min(abs(i - z), abs(i - next_z)))
    return dist
```

Another approach is to build `dist` in two passes -- first sweep forward through the list and decrease the potential value of `dist` based on how long it's been since you last saw a zero, then sweep backward and do the same thing, setting the minimum value each time.

```
def zero_dist(nums: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    d = len(nums)
    dist = [d for _ in nums]  # will return this if no zeroes
    for e in (
        enumerate(nums),
        ((len(nums) - i, n) for i, n in enumerate(reversed(nums), 1))
    ):
        for i, n in e:
            if n == 0:
                d = 0
            else:
                d += 1
            dist[i] = min(d, dist[i])
    return dist
```

Comment: Thanks, beautiful solution but it is indeed not very time efficient

Comment: Note that it’s still significantly more time efficient than your original solution (which is O(n^2) even when there’s only one zero), which is why I didn’t sweat the efficiency.  :). The more complex solution of iterating forward and backward is probably the one I’d pick if I needed it to be O(n) in the general case.

Comment: For funsies I added a couple of O(n) solutions.  In practice, I would probably use the less-efficient (and easier to understand) solution as long as I knew I was always working with a relatively small list of numbers (or a relatively small number of zeroes), and would only bust out a more algorithmically complex solution if I had reason to believe that performance on large lists was going to be important.

Answer (score 0):

This works for any number of Zeros by first finding their locations and working out all distances from zeros then taking the minimums:

```
lst = [2, 1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 7]

pos0 = [i for i,j in enumerate(lst) if j == 0]

result = []
for i in pos0:
    res = [abs(i-a) for a, b in enumerate(lst)]
    result.append(res)
    

final = [min(a) for a in zip(*result)]

print(final)

# prints [2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: The line with variable "final" causes an error: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

Comment: My mistake. Now edited to correct for any number of zeros

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to implement a one-pass solution that will be O(n) time and O(1) space. This can even be written as a generator function that will accept any iterable as input.

For series or non-zeroes (except the first and last) the distances will increase from one up to half the size of the series and decrease back to 1.  If the list starts with non-zeroes, their distances will decrease only.  If the list ends with non-zeroes, their distance will only increase.  So if we build the result based on increasing (forward) distances, we only need to generate the increasing and/or decreasing series of numbers based on the length of sequences of non-zero values.

For example:

This list of numbers with two zero entries contains all the possible patterns:

```
 9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9
|-----------|  |--------------|  |----------| 
|  leading  |  | intermediate |  | trailing |
|-----------|  |--------------|  |----------| 
 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

The `leading` sequence of non-zero (up to the first zero) will always have decreasing distances

The `intermediate` sequence of non-zero (between zeros) will increase up to half its length and then decrease back to 1.  Having more zeros in the list will only add more of these intermediate sequences.

The `trailing` sequence of non-zero (after the last zero) will only increase.

Based on this the generator function can produce the result as it moves forward through the iterator, generating the distance numbers from ranges as it encounters the zero values.

```
def dist20(L):
    seenZero = False
    nonZeros = 0
    for n in L:
        if n:
            nonZeros += 1                             # length of non-zeros
        else:
            if seenZero:
                yield from range(1,(nonZeros+1)//2+1) # intermediate
                yield from range(nonZeros//2,0,-1)
            else:
                yield from range(nonZeros,0,-1)       # leading
            yield 0                                   # zero itself
            nonZeros = 0
            seenZero = True
    if seenZero:
        yield from range(1,nonZeros+1)                # trailing
    else:
        yield from (None for _ in range(nonZeros))    # no zeros found
```

output:

```
L = [2, 1, 0, 3, 5, 3, 0, 2, 1]
iL = iter(L)                     # doesn't have to be an actual iterator
print(*dist20(iL))               # iter(L) is only for demonstration purposes.
# 2 1 0 1 2 1 0 1 2              # print(*dist20(L)) would also work
```